# Windows Azure Emulator stops working after upgrade to SQL Server 2012

Tags: azure, sql-server-2012

I recently installed the SQL Server 2012. After the installation I had to run the DSInit command.

When I launch a web role on my local machine I get the message - "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". The Web roles ceased to work; there an no errors on the emulator console.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

On uninstalling SQL Server 2012 and reinstalling with a named instance rather than the default instance sorted the issue